# Returning null values in DAO file

Tags: java, spring

I created one DAO file but while debugging time and in browser getting null value but in database it storing the values..
and also while debugging time, the compiler going to catch block..
can anybody find my error..

Comment: In `ceBean.get("asessmentBean ");` if `asessmentBean` is supposed to be some id then I doubt it might contain a trailing space.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning null, have your exception record the error info so you can diagnose it properly yourself:

```
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Obviously there is more to good logging practice, error handling, etc, than just this, but it could move you forward.

Comment: yaah its shows in browser but only 1st time if i insert more value then values saving in database but in browser override it and null value shows meaning nothing is there

Comment: Use queryForList instead of queryForObject, then choose the element(s) in the list you want to show in your page. Your issue is, as DaveHowes above suggests, you're expecting 1 result back but getting several.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your SQL statement is returning more than one row - from the docs for `queryForObject`

> The query is expected to be a single row/single column query; the returned result will be directly mapped to the corresponding object type.

If you are returning more than one row, an `IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException` will be thrown, resulting in your method returning null.